# Process stop getting network data

Tags: networking, tcp, freeze

We have a process (written in c++ /managed), which receives network data via tcpip.
After running the process for a while while tracking network load, it seems that network get into freeze state and the process does not getting data, there are other processes in the system that using networking (same nic) which operates normally.
the process gets out of this frozen situation by itself after several minutes.

Any idea what is happening?
Any counter i can track to see if my process reach some limitations ?

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be very difficult to answer specifically, 
-- without knowing what exactly is your process/application about,

-- whether it is a network chat application, or  a file server/client, or ......

-- without other details about your process how it is implemented, what libraries it uses, if relevant to problem.

Also you haven't mentioned what OS and environment you are running this process under, 
   there is very little anyone can help . It could be anything, a busy wait loopl in your code,  locking problems if its a multi-threaded code,....
 Nonetheless , here are some options to check:

If its linux try below commands to debug and monitor the behaviour of the process and see   what could be problem-

1. top 
   Check top to see ow much resources(CPU, memory) your process is using and if there is anything abnormally high values in CPU usage for it.
2. pstack 
   This should stack frames of the process executing at time of the problem.
3. netstat 
   Run this with necessary options (tcp/udp) to check what is the stae of the network sockets opened by your process
4. gcore -s -c    
   This  forces your process to core when the mentioned problem happens, and then analyze that core file using gdb 
   gdb 
     and then use command where at gdb prompt to get full back trace of the process (which functions it was executing last and previous function calls.